# dd() not show the collection in laravel but show in inspect network

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, var-dump

The main problem is dd() is not showing anything in the browser(both chrome and firefox) in my entire project for any variable. there i mention one example. i can save and do all other stuffs but dd() show nothing.
In my controller i use the below code...

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $file = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->storeAs('public/images', $filename);

        $empData = [
            'first_name' => $request->fname,
            'last_name' => $request->lname,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'post' => $request->post,
            'avatar' => $filename,
        ];

        dd($empData);
```

there dd($empData); show just nothing. when i inspect the code i see the below result in network preview-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TThD.jpg)

array:6 [ "first_name" => "ff" "last_name" => "ff" "email" => "f@m.com"
"phone" => "45435" "post" => "543534" "avatar" => "1656478823.jpg"]

why dd() show nothing in browser ?? I have some other projects and they are working fine. this project the laravel version is 8

Comment: post your routes and your frontend code as well.

Comment: this is the route -- Route::post('/store', [EmployeeController::class, 'store'])->name('store');  everything is ok, i can also save but the issue is dd() is not working in my entire project.

Comment: How you're calling the store function?

Comment: Check if you aren't using a library that defines its own dd function or that you aren't defining your own dd function somewhere else.  The function will only be defined if it's not already defined at the time that composer loads the file that defines it. This will be a time consuming check probably, but check a file called `autoload_static.php` under your `vendor/composer` folder. The line that loads the symfony dd is something like `'.....' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php',` so any file loaded before this may have overwritten `dd`

Comment: This also occurs when you are working with AJAX

Comment: yeah, that is happenning. its for ajax. when i submit the post request from ajax it happen that time. browser dont show the collection but i can see by inspect the browser. is there any way to see through the browser??

Comment: If you use an AJAX request, then you won't get a dump in the browser itself since the `dd` shown in the console is the response that is returned. If you want to show it in the browser, you should use a form with a POST action directly, not an AJAX submit. 

What's wrong with displaying it in the console, however?

Comment: in another place i used a form for change password, that also dont work.  this is the blade  ---<form method="post" action="{{ route('update.pass') }}"> ---   this is the route----Route::post('/password/update', [HomeController::class, 'updatePassword'])->name('update.pass'); -----this is the controller -------public function updatePassword(Request $request)
    {

        dd($request->all()); ----------  this also not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the route/function through an ajax request? If so, this is why your dd is showing in the network panel

Comment: Yes, later I understood it . Thanks for comment.